# bind an event listener to a newly rendered dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to bind an event to a newly rendered dynamic elements, below is my attempt.

```
<div id="app">
    <a href="#" @click="loadData">Load Data</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="collections" v-for="item in collections" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

new Vue({
  el : '#app',
  data : {
    files : []
  },
  mounted(){
    const _self = this;
    axios.get('myapi.com/api/users',{})
    .then(function(res){
      _self.files = res.data.users;

      // add event
      document.querySelectorAll('.collections').forEach(function(el){
        _self.$ons.GestureDetector(el).on("hold", function(event) {
          alert();
        });
      });

    });
  },
  computed : {
    collections(){
      return this.files;
    }
  },
  methods : {
    loadData(){
      const _self = this;
      axios.get('myapi.con/api/users/2',{})
      .then(function(res){
        _self.files = res.data.users;
        document.querySelectorAll('.collections').forEach(function(el){
            _self.$ons.GestureDetector(el).on("hold", function(event) {
                alert();
            });
        });
      });
    }
  }

});
```

seems updating the element on the DOM tree is in asynchronous way as I tried to do `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.collections').length)` returns `0` and via console, it returns the actual count of the target elements.

Note: the manual binding for the event has its own purpose or intention. I can truly use @click which standard on Vue.

Comment: These are just standard elements created by a `v-for`.  You should use `@click` on them and define their event handlers in whatever method you pass to it.

Comment: the manual binding for the event has its own purpose or intention. I can truly use @click which standard on Vue.

Comment: I have updated the code above with the actual code on my app, I'm using Onsen UI + Vue and attempting to add a gesture event to each of the dynamic elements. The problem is,  I think the rendering of the elements is asynchronous?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the purpose/intention of binding the event handler in JS vs the template?

Comment: @tony19 this is for attaching the event '_self.$ons.GestureDetector' to all of the target elements that has a class of '.collections'

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues:  1) Implementing a custom `hold` event from a 3rd party library, and, 2) Accessing the DOM of a `v-for` item after it's mounted.  Because of these, you should use a component for each `collections` item and use the `mounted` hook in that component:

1.
Create a custom component for the `collections` items, passing the item as a prop

```js
Vue.component('collection-item', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: `<li>{{ item.name }}</li>`,
  mounted() {
    // THIS IS WHERE YOU'LL PLACE YOUR CUSTOM EVENT
    // No need for `_self` when you use an arrow function
    // this.$el points to the DOM element
    this.$ons.GestureDetector(this.$el).on("hold", event => {
      alert(event);
    });
  }
})
```

2.
Adjust your template

```html
<ul>
  <collection-item v-for="item in collections" :key="item.id" :item="item" />
</ul>
```

3.
Remove all of the event handler code from the main app component

Notice some things:

- In the custom component's `mounted` hook, you can use `this.$el` to point to the DOM element.
- If you use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you don't need the `_self` trick.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/wz91f74b/) that won't work only because it doesn't know what `GestureDetector` is, but will help you understand.